# UWP Capture video from camera then send over socket (TCP)

Tags: c#

I want to capture the camera video then send to the other machine over socket with TCP protocol. I use the Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture to capture the video, the code as below:

```
 private async Task StartVideoAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                //Creat log object
                lc = new LoggingChannel("LyLog", null, new Guid("B5F3B8E9-A854-4045-A6DE-A7C4FF8FA114"));
                lc.LogMessage("LoggingChannel create success");

                //Creat video capture object
                mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
                lc.LogMessage("MediaCapture create success");

                //Set video capture property 
                var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
                settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
                await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
                lc.LogMessage("Set Capture property success");

                //Creat media profile
                var recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
                lc.LogMessage("Create media profile success");

                //Creat media stream
                m_stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                lc.LogMessage("Create media stream success");

                //Start recording 
                await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(recordProfile, m_stream);
                lc.LogMessage("Start recording success");
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) 
            {
                //There's no camera access
                lc.LogMessage("The app was denied access to the camera");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lc.LogMessage(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I have two question: 
1.Use this way to capture the data in stream is mp4 format.How can I get the  h.264 video data?
2.How can I send the h.264 data over socket?

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer? I am looking for nearly the same. Thank you.